# Replacing script tags from java string

Tags: java, regex, string

Consider the below String

```
String html = "<div>test> <div /><script > docuement.alert()
                                                     </script> <p>ptag</p>";
```

I used regex to get it done by replacing script tags

```
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)<script.*?(/>|</script>)", ""));
```

That gave

```
<div >test> <div />suresh >   <p>ptag</p>
```

But I have been asked to convert into

```
<div >test> <div />&lt;script &gt;  docuement.alert()
                                                     &lt;/script &gt; <p>ptag</p>
```

With `subString` and `indexOf`  I can achieve this , but i'm no clue of how to do it with a regex.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using regex to accomplish this task instead of a HTML parser library like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)? Not sure if you have read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I suspect that HTML parsers can have problems with something like `<div>test>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Tried and such a weird framework. When I gave my string, in result it is appending `body` and `html` tags.

Comment: are you sure that the `>` from `test>` must not be replaced?

Comment: Yes, only those symbols for script tags

Comment: Are you trying to prevent a XSS attack? Regex would not be sufficient. jsoup does have [tools](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) that may be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
s.replaceAll("(?i)<(/?script[^>]*)>", "&lt;$1&gt;")
```

This will find

- `(?i)` case insensitive flag
- `<`
- optional `/` after it
- `script` literal, thanks to `(?i)` it will also match `script`, `ScrIPt`, `SCRIPT`, ...
- `[^>]*` zero of more non `>` characters
- `>`

Using parenthesis I am placing part between `<` and `>` in group 1 which later can be used in replacement via `$1`.

---

Demo

```
String s = "<div >suresh > <div />suresh >  <script > docuement.alert()"
        + " </script> <p>ptag</p>";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)<(/?script[^>]*)>", "&lt;$1&gt;"));
```

output:

```
<div >suresh > <div />suresh >  &lt;script &gt; docuement.alert() &lt;/script&gt; <p>ptag</p>
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ In case you will be interested in learning regex you should take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html I've learned most of regex from it and [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation.